# 403 on /?wc-ajax=update_shipping_method

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, nonce

/?wc-ajax=update_shipping_method is giving me 403 response with the contents of "-1". Because of this, payment methods do not refresh based on the selected delivery method.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting a cache issue here, Most of the Ajax requests require nonce for the security checks and if You're using a cache plugin then it's possible the nonce value is also stored on the cache, and because of that nonce validation is failing and you're getting 403 response.

The nonce value changes every 12 or 24 hours (I am not sure about the exact time period), so validation with the old nonce value will always fail.

Try to disable your cache plugin and if you're using cdn then purge the cache then force reload the page then test the issue.